# "untouched" vs "intact" vs "unblemished"

Tags: meaning, poetry

According to the Google dictionary these three words are synonyms.

How would you order them in terms of which is more literary?

Which one can be used more appropriately in a poetical context such in the following poetic line:
"...our love remained untouched/intact/unblemished throughout the years..." ?

Comment: And probably `pristine`. I think something being `touched`, still could be `intact`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Nice thought. I would be also interested to have my questions answered by including also the word `pristine`.

Comment: What does it mean to be “literary”?  If it means how often is it used in books, then this graph is helpful: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=intact%2Cunblemished%2Cuntouched&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cintact%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunblemished%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cuntouched%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 0):

Really it depends upon the style/era/period with which the author is attempting to convey. 'Pure' is a word oft associated with "love"; and another option might be 'sans blemish' as opposed to "unblemished".

If attempting to use a more modern term, then 'scraggle' might fit the bill as is used in urban fare.

Answer (score 0):

**“untouched”** - Connotes a lack of contact with humans. "These ancient trees were a remote, untouched region of the forest". Usage is fairly rare and would often be in a phrase explaining the meaning, like "untouched by human hands". Saying "our love remained untouched throughout the years" sounds super-weird, like you put your love up on a shelf and didn't think about it for a couple of decades.

**“intact”** - A common general-purpose word, for most purposes it is identical to saying "not broken" with little connotation. Something might have a few dents or dings, but it is still functional for ordinary purposes. Saying "our love remained intact throughout the years" means that you had a few arguments and differences, but you are still in love despite them. Of the three words, this is the only version of that sentence I can imagine saying to my wife, twenty years from now.

**“unblemished”** - A blemish is a mar, a mark, a spot, some sort of loss of aesthetics but not functionality. The connotation is out-of-the-box pristine shiny-ness. It is a word that a eBay seller of camera lenses might say. Or you might say of a young person "His/her skin was unblemished by the cares and wrinkles of old age." Saying "our love remained unblemished throughout the years" sounds like you had a perfect, flawless love for all that time. It seems to imply a lack of problems or troubles, an idyllic love that never had any real-world problems. To me it comes across a little creepy or overly idealistic and sentimental, but it's better than "untouched" which just sounds straight-up wrong.

@Poete_Maudit, everything about unblemished applies to **pristine**, they are very close words. Pristine is a bit more general-purpose in that it makes you think more of cleanliness or perfection itself, rather than a lack of flaws that "unblemished" evokes. You hear "pristine forest" pretty often. "Unblemished forest", while not technically incorrect and a native English speaker might say it, sounds a bit odd unless you are highlighting something that might go wrong ("a forest that is so far unblemished by the logging industry" perhaps). "Unblemished" tends to be used for things where you would expect a "blemish" but there isn't one. While it can be used metaphorically (as in my forest example), a blemish is most often an imperfection on a surface, like camera lenses or skin, and so "unblemished" is most often used literally to describe an absence of such a thing.